# Differences between return function in python and Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

Comparing MATLAB and Python, it appears that there are some differences between return command in Python vs MATLAB. Is there an exact equivalent for MATLAB return function in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the return keyword is different in a Python function vs. a MATLAB function.

In a MATLAB function, the Left Hand Side (LHS) arguments define what needs to be defined within the function body prior to returning.

```
function y = foo(x)
    y = 1;
 end
```

If you use a return statement to end execution of the function early, you still are responsible for correctly populating the LHS argument list of the function

```
function y = foo(x)
    y = 1;
    return;
    y = 2;
end
```

In this example, foo returns 1 as y because the function body defines y to be 1, before execution returns to the caller after the return statement.

In python, the return statement ends execution AND also defines what (if any) values are returned by a function, there is no output argument list in a python function definition.

```
def foo(x):
    return 1;
```

Because you need to use the return keyword in python to return values from a function, return tends to be a more heavily used construct than return in MATLAB function definitions.